# Sum of solutions of this exponential equations

Tags: logarithms

How to solve this :

$$x^{3-\log_{10}(x/3)}=900$$

I tried log on both sides and got nothing with exponent of $x$ and $3$.

Comment: Can you write what you've done?

Comment: I will post a picture :

Comment: [Pic](http://i.imgur.com/Kmboje3.jpg)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Go ahead and take the $\log_{10}$ on both sides:
$$3\log_{10}(x)-\log_{10}(x)^2+\log_{10}(x)\log_{10}(3)=\log_{10}(900).$$
Now solve the quadratic.
Let $y=\log_{10}(x).$ Then this quadratic is
$$y^2-(\log_{10}(3)+3)y+\log_{10}(900)=0.$$
Applying the quadratic formula, we get
$$y=\frac{3+\log_{10}(3)\pm\sqrt{\log_{10}(3)^2+6\log_{10}(3)+9-4\log_{10}(900)}}{2}$$
$$=\frac{3+\log_{10}(3)\pm\sqrt{\log_{10}(3)^2+6\log_{10}(3)+9-8\log_{10}(3)-8}}{2}$$
$$=\frac{3+\log_{10}(3)\pm\sqrt{\log_{10}(3)^2-2\log_{10}(3)+1}}{2}$$
$$=\frac{3+\log_{10}(3)\pm(\log_{10}(3)-1)}{2}$$
$$=\cases{1+\log_{10}(3)=\log_{10}(30)\\2}$$

Thus, $x=30$ or $x=100$.

Comment: I guess it is something like this $$-log^2_{10}(x)$$. I don't know how to solve this there is a picture above this post, I tried that.

Comment: I got here but what should I do next. I need to get the sum of solutions by $$x$$

Comment: I found the mistake we both made. We said $\log(9)=3\log(3)$, not $2\log(3)$. See my edited answer.

Comment: Thank you I have also made a mistake probably.

Answer (score 1):

Take the log base $10$ of both sides, and let $u = \log_{10}(x)$. Then the expression turns into a quadratic in terms of $u$, which you can solve.

Comment: the solutions are 30 and 100, so the quadratic has one solution at $u=2$

Comment: How did you get the solutions?

Comment: You just want the sum of solutions, right? You can get that by using Vieta's formulae. It will be $3 + \log_{10}(3)$.